# Spark Scala - Select all records between date and date + 24 hours from another view

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables, a master table and a lookup table that contains a Date that I want to select all records from the master table that are within 24 hours of that lookup date.

maxDiff Table:

```
+------------+------------------+-------+-------+----------+
|TemperatureF|              Date|MinTemp|MaxTemp|Difference|
+------------+------------------+-------+-------+----------+
|        37.9|01/29/2008 5:53 AM|  -11.9|   39.2|      51.1|
+------------+------------------+-------+-------+----------+
```

This table only contains a single row. I want to use this date, to look up all records within 24 hours of this date. (Date+24).

Sample of oshView (master table):

```
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|TemperatureF|               Date|timestamp|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|        39.0| 01/29/2008 4:53 AM|1201582380|  -11.0|   39.2|
|        37.9| 01/29/2008 5:53 AM|1201585980|  -11.9|   39.2|
|        37.9| 01/29/2008 6:53 AM|1201589580|  -11.9|   39.2|
|        37.4| 01/29/2008 7:38 AM|1201592280|  -11.9|   39.2|
|        37.0| 01/29/2008 7:53 AM|1201593180|  -11.9|   39.2|
|        37.4| 01/29/2008 8:11 AM|1201594260|  -11.9|   39.2|
|        -9.4| 01/30/2008 3:30 AM|1201663800|  -11.9|    1.9|
|       -11.0| 01/30/2008 3:53 AM|1201665180|  -11.9|    1.9|
|       -11.0| 01/30/2008 4:53 AM|1201668780|  -11.9|    1.9|
|       -11.9| 01/30/2008 5:53 AM|1201672380|  -11.9|    1.9|
|       -11.9| 01/30/2008 6:53 AM|1201675980|  -11.9|    1.9|
|       -11.9| 01/30/2008 7:53 AM|1201679580|  -11.9|    1.9|
|         1.0| 01/30/2008 4:53 PM|1201711980|   -2.0|   12.0|
|         1.0| 01/30/2008 5:53 PM|1201715580|   -2.0|   12.9|
|         0.0| 01/30/2008 6:53 PM|1201719180|   -2.0|   12.9|
|         0.0| 01/30/2008 7:53 PM|1201722780|   -2.0|   12.9|
|        -0.9| 01/30/2008 8:53 PM|1201726380|   -2.0|   14.0|
|        -0.9| 01/30/2008 9:53 PM|1201729980|   -2.0|   15.8|
|        -0.9|01/30/2008 10:53 PM|1201733580|   -2.0|   16.0|
|        -0.9|01/30/2008 11:53 PM|1201737180|   -2.0|   16.0|
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|TemperatureF|               Date|timestamp|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|        35.1|01/30/2008 12:53 AM|946687980|   28.0|   36.0|
|        35.1| 01/30/2008 1:53 AM|946691580|   28.0|   36.0|
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
```

I tried the following, but receive an empty result.

```
spark.sqlContext.sql("Select * from oshView where Date between (Select Date from maxDiff) AND (Select Date from maxDiff) + INTERVAL 1 DAY").show()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` and `Timestamp` values in your master Dataframe don't seem to match, hence I'm going to use column `Date` in both the DataFrames (less error-prone anyway) and apply `unix_timestamp` to compare their time difference as the `join` condition:

```
val lookup = Seq(
  (37.9, "01/29/2008 5:53 AM")
).toDF("TemperatureF", "Date")

val master = Seq(
  (35.1, "01/29/2008 4:53 AM", 1201582380, -11.0, 39.2),
  (37.9, "01/29/2008 5:53 AM", 1201585980, -11.9, 39.2),
  (-11.0, "01/30/2008 4:53 AM", 1201668780, -11.9, 1.9),
  (-11.0, "01/30/2008 5:53 AM", 1201672380, -11.9, 1.9),
  (-11.9, "01/30/2008 6:53 AM", 1201675980, -11.9, 1.9)
).toDF("TemperatureF", "Date", "Timestamp", "MinTemp", "MaxTemp")

val dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"
val deltaTime = 60 * 60 * 24

master.join(
  lookup,
  unix_timestamp(master("Date"), dateFormat) - unix_timestamp(lookup("Date"), dateFormat)
    between (0, deltaTime)
).show
// +------------+------------------+----------+-------+-------+------------+------------------+
// |TemperatureF|              Date| Timestamp|MinTemp|MaxTemp|TemperatureF|              Date|
// +------------+------------------+----------+-------+-------+------------+------------------+
// |        37.9|01/29/2008 5:53 AM|1201585980|  -11.9|   39.2|        37.9|01/29/2008 5:53 AM|
// |       -11.0|01/30/2008 4:53 AM|1201668780|  -11.9|    1.9|        37.9|01/29/2008 5:53 AM|
// |       -11.0|01/30/2008 5:53 AM|1201672380|  -11.9|    1.9|        37.9|01/29/2008 5:53 AM|
// +------------+------------------+----------+-------+-------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: When I try to incorporate this into my code, it's performing a cartesian product and returning all rows from the master, not only the ones within the 24 hour timeframe.

Comment: @peakstatus, based on the `join` condition, all rows in `master` will be included ONLY IF each of them has a corresponding row in `lookup` within a 24-hour time range.  Why don't you edit your sample data with a minimal dataset that demonstrates the said problem, so I can help look into possible causes?

Comment: I updated my data for my Master table. This shows the whole picture of what I'm looking for. When looking at the data in the Master table, you can see that the MinTemp/MaxTemp occur within a 24 hour period of my input data. 5:53 AM on 01/29/2008 for the Max, and -11.9 at 5:53 AM on 1/30/2008. My lookup table date indicates the beginning of this timeframe. I just want to select all records up to 24 hours after this record. So from my master table, I only want records from 01/29/2008 5:53 AM, to 01/30/2008 5:53 AM. Does that help clarify my question?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your requirement then.  Just remove the `abs` function and modify the `join` condition as shown in my revised answer, and it should return the wanted result.

Comment: This works great, I appreciate your insight to this.